# SQL Server 2008 R2 installation device error

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to install SQL Server 2008 R2 to use along with Visual Studio for a website I am creating.

However when I am installing SQL Server I am constantly getting the following error:

> The services could not be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.

I have tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it and the problem still occurs.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio?  Also have you tried to assign a domain account to run the services?

Comment: Have a look at this [`Answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869934/sql-server-2008-installation-error-message-unable-to-open-windows-installer-fil)